Counting groups of like values within the same column
I have a dataframe containing columns with groups of 1's and -1's. Each column could contain any amount of 1's or -1's grouped together within each column, and they could also begin with an unspecified number of NaN's. I would like to count the total of values within each group excluding the NaN's.
An example dataframe is below:
NaN = float('nan')
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,1],
                   'col2':[NaN, NaN, NaN, 1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1],
                   'col3':[NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,1,1,1,-1]})

I would like the output to be another dataframe as shown below:
df =  pd.DataFrame({'col1':[4,4,4,4,3,3,3,2,2],
                    'col2':[NaN, NaN, NaN,2,2,4,4,4,4],
                    'col3': [NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,3,3,3,1]})


Please provide a [mre] as DataFrame/Series for clarity, not python list.

Assuming a DataFrame/Series, you can group the successive values and use a groupby.transform('size'):
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1]})
df['out'] = (df.groupby(df['col'].ne(df['col'].shift()).cumsum())
               .transform('size')
            )

Output:
    col  out
0     1    5
1     1    5
2     1    5
3     1    5
4     1    5
5    -1    4
6    -1    4
7    -1    4
8    -1    4
9     1    3
10    1    3
11    1    3

If your input is a list, not need for pandas, go with itertools.groupby/itertools.chain:
from itertools import groupby, chain

lst = [1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1]
out = list(chain.from_iterable([l:=len(list(g))]*l for _, g in groupby(lst)))

Output:
[5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3]

multiple columns
If you have a DataFrame with multiple columns, you can transform each column independently with apply and mask the NaNs:
NaN = float('nan')
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,1],
                   'col2':[NaN, NaN, NaN, 1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1],
                   'col3':[NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,1,1,1,-1]})

out = df.apply(lambda s: s.groupby(s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum())
                          .transform('size').mask(s.isna()))

Output:
   col1  col2  col3
0     4   NaN   NaN
1     4   NaN   NaN
2     4   NaN   NaN
3     4   2.0   NaN
4     3   2.0   NaN
5     3   4.0   3.0
6     3   4.0   3.0
7     2   4.0   3.0
8     2   4.0   1.0


Thank you for the answer. What would be the modification to the code if I wanted to apply it to a whole dataframe with various groups of 1's and -1's? As I would not use the df['col'] part?

For example if I had a dataframe df = pd.Dataframe({'col1':[1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1], 'col2':[1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1]})

@Kevin then what would be the expected output? The same per column? or would you have one output column using all the initial columns as grouper? Note that your example is invalid (the lists have a different length).

It would be another dataframe with the same columns df = {'col1':[5,5,5,5,5,4,4,4,4,3,3,3], 'col2':[2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4]}

If you want to apply the transformation for each column independently: df.apply(lambda s: s.groupby(s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum()).transform('size')).

Thanks! What if now I had columns where some had NaN at the start, for example df = {'col1': [NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1], 'col2': [NaN, NaN,-1,-1,-1,1,1], 'col3':[1,1,-1,-1,-1]}. I would like the same solution as before, but the entries with NaN would not have a number. Using the current solution, they fill with a '1' value.

@Kevin please be explicit: edit your question with all the details. Also be aware that this is not a discussion forum, you should take time to clearly write your question, then the logic shouldn't change.

Apologies, I have now edited the question.

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


NaN = float('nan')
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': [1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1],
    'col2': [NaN, NaN, NaN, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
    'col3': [NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 1, 1, 1, -1]
})
print(df)
'''
   col1  col2  col3
0     1   NaN   NaN
1     1   NaN   NaN
2     1   NaN   NaN
3     1   1.0   NaN
4    -1   1.0   NaN
5    -1  -1.0   1.0
6    -1  -1.0   1.0
7     1  -1.0   1.0
8     1  -1.0  -1.0
'''

def f(s):
    m = s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum()
    streak_length = s.groupby(m).transform('size')
    return s.where(s.isna(),streak_length)
    
result_df = df.apply(f)
print(result_df)
'''
   col1  col2  col3
0     4   NaN   NaN
1     4   NaN   NaN
2     4   NaN   NaN
3     4   2.0   NaN
4     3   2.0   NaN
5     3   4.0   3.0
6     3   4.0   3.0
7     2   4.0   3.0
8     2   4.0   1.0
'''


You started well with value_counts() to get for each value what is the number of occurences. Once you get that you can then apply replace to replace values in the Series
See this example :
import pandas as pd

df = pd.Series([1,1,1,-1])

count = df.value_counts().to_dict()

df = df.replace(count)

